# Can't disable WriteProperties task

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I need to write a properties file only if two environment variables are present. My use-case is if I'm running through an IDE (IntelliJ/Android Studio), this properties file is automatically generated by the IDE (and the global environment variables are not available to the IDE), but when compiled from terminal I need to generate it myself.

My problem is that I can't seem to ever disable the task. Here's my task:

```
task createLocalProperties(type: WriteProperties) {
    String sdkDir = System.getenv('ANDROID_HOME')
    String ndkDir = System.getenv('ANDROID_NDK_HOME')
    File propFile = file('../local.properties')
    project.logger.info('Creating local.properties')
    property('sdk.dir', sdkDir)
    property('ndk.dir', ndkDir)
    setOutputFile(propFile)
    writeProperties()
}
createLocalProperties.onlyIf { !System.getenv('ANDROID_HOME')?.isEmpty() && !System.getenv('ANDROID_NDK_HOME')?.isEmpty() }
```

Replacing the conditional in the `onlyIf` with `false` still runs the task. Setting `createLocalProperties.enabled false` still runs the task. I'm not sure exactly why there seems to be no way to prevent this task from running.

Comment: Try wrapping the actual task job in doLast { ... } block. As it's written now everything got executed on configuration stage, while onlyIf can only be effective on execution stage.

Comment: @Jk1 tried that. When I do that, then the properties file is never written even when the onlyIf condition is true. It's my understanding that doLast happens after the task has executed, so my configuration would be too late. I need to configure and run the task only if a condition is met. I could wrap the whole thing in an if-statement, but I was hopping to get the SKIPPED text to show up to document whether the task executed.